# Why doesn't dictionary tuples respect the construction order?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

So, I construct a dictionary (with tuples) in python using this code:

```
d = { (x , x + 1) : x for x in range(0 , 10)}
print(d)
```

And I end up printing `{(0, 1): 0, (1, 2): 1, (6, 7): 6, (5, 6): 5, (7, 8): 7, (8, 9): 8, (4, 5): 4, (2, 3): 2, (9, 10): 9, (3, 4): 3}`

My question is: why doesn't it respect a specific order, the one I used for constructing the dictionary?

Comment: You would appear to be using an older version of Python. CPython 3.6 preserved insertion order as an implication detail; Python 3.7 requires *all* implementations to preserve insertion order. If you are stuck using an older version, you need to use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module.

Comment: what version of python you have?

Answer (score 0):

if your [python version is < 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) you can use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the insertion order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict(((x , x + 1), x) for x in range(0 , 10))
d
```

output:

```
OrderedDict([((0, 1), 0),
             ((1, 2), 1),
             ((2, 3), 2),
             ((3, 4), 3),
             ((4, 5), 4),
             ((5, 6), 5),
             ((6, 7), 6),
             ((7, 8), 7),
             ((8, 9), 8),
             ((9, 10), 9)])
```